# how to make a custom tooltip in a Kendo Chart?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendos StockChart with Razor/MVC.

When my user hovers overs over a item in the series I want a friendly string **that contains data bound data**,  not just the value or the category.

```
class Node
{
    public int Value {get; set;}
    public DateTime Date { get; set;}
    public string InterestingInfo { get; set;}
}

@(Html.Kendo().StockChart<Node>()
        .Name("chart") 
        .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read.Action("_X", "Controller")))
        .DateField("Date")
        .Series(series => {
            series.Line(model => model.Value);
        })
        .Navigator(nav => nav
            .DataSource(ds => ds .Read(read => read.Action("_X", "Controller")))
            .Series(series =>
            {
                series.Area(s => s.Value);
            })
        )       
        .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
            .Visible(true)
            .Shared(false)
            .Template("#=InterestingInfo#")
        )
      )
)
```

No matter what I use in the Template, I cant seem to get anything but 'undefined' in the tooltip

I've tried, but honestly I'm not sure what I'm doing, who processes these (is it jquery, kendo, etc)

```
 #=data.InterestingInfo#
 #=dataItem.InterestingInfo#
```

Answer (score 4):

As a general Kendo UI tip, if you can't seem to get the values in your template to print, you can make your template:

```
"#console.log(data)#"
```

then check the console in the dev tools. You should be able to figure out what is being passed to your template that way.

Answer (score 4):

In your Node class, add this:

```
class Node
{
    public int Value {get; set;}
    public DateTime Date { get; set;}
    public string InterestingInfo { get; set;}
    public string Tooltip { get; set; }
}
```

In your read method 'MethodX' in your controller, populate the Tooltip property with whatever you  want. From there, you can use this code:

```
.Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
        .Visible(true)
        .Shared(false)
        .Template("#= dataItem.Tooltip #")
    )
```

The dataItem is processed by kendo and it is that data for that particular bound object. The '#= stuff here #' is kendo syntax for template data. Good luck!

Comment: An amazing idea. When I had to build my template for a big List , this really helps